# tensorflow restore model and do inference failed with Dataset iterator initialization failure error

Tags: tensorflow

I restored trained model as below

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('expr1.multi/train_logs/model.ckpt-44.meta')
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
saver.restore(sess,'expr1.multi/train_logs/model.ckpt-44')
```

and then retrieve the tensors needed for inference as

```
logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name('strided_slice_1:0')
logits_len = graph.get_tensor_by_name('strided_slice_2:0')
targets = graph.get_tensor_by_name('evaluate/IteratorGetNext:2')
targets_len = graph.get_tensor_by_name('evaluate/IteratorGetNext:3')

# this is to retrieve the dataset.iterator.initializer operator
init_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('evaluate/MakeIterator')
```

then do the inference

```
sess.run(init_op)
while True:
    try:
        l, ll, t, tl = sess.run([logits, logits_len, targets, targets_len])
        ...
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
```

and in case for model trained with single gpu training above model restoring and inference works fine without issue. However with below multiple gpu training (asynchronous) implementation, it failed

```
    loss_ops = []
    train_ops = []
    for gpu_i in range(self.num_gpus):
        with tf.device("/gpu:%d" % gpu_i):
            loss = ...
            # update the model parameter
            update = self.model.update(loss, global_step, self.lrate, self.grad_clip)
            loss_ops.append(loss)
            train_ops.append(update)

    # within this Dataset pipe is created for evaluation data
    evaluator = get_evaluator(self.evaluator)(self.conf, self.model)

    mon_sess = tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(config=config, hooks=hooks)
    ...

    def train_helper(train_op, loss_op):
        ...
        while not mon_sess.should_stop() and has_data:
            try:
                _, lossVal, step = mon_sess.run([train_op, loss_op, global_step])
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                has_data = False
                continue

            #validation loss evaluation every eval_steps steps
            if not step == 0 and step % self.eval_steps == 0:

                # one shot iterator initialization done inside evaluate function
                val_lossVal, num_utts = evaluator.evaluate(mon_sess)
                ...

    train_threads = []
    for t_op, loss_op in zip(train_ops, loss_ops):
        train_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=train_helper, args=(t_op, loss_op)))

    # Start the threads, and block on their completion.
    for t in train_threads:
        t.start()
    for t in train_threads:
        t.join()
```

below dataset pipe iterator initialization failing error

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.

I could not figure out the reason.

Comment: anyone can help on this? thanks!